# Isn't moderated-deletion fundamentally different than self-deletion, which requires different kinds of deletion policy?

Tags: feature-request, moderation, deleted-answers, moderator-abilities

[Recently I have had a bunch of answers deleted by a moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122663/179067). I've learned that by reviewing a question I had recently answered and saw my question deleted. It was OK, most of the answers needed improvement. The problem is, I was inclined to improve them, but they weren't at my profile anymore! I have asked the moderator for a list of this answers and [he kindly gave them as an answer to a meta stackoverflow complain question I've created](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122679/179067).

Isn't it a bit extreme to have a bunch of answers deleted without even knowing they were? Shouldn't they stay at your profile, marked as deleted so you get the chance to improve them?

Now the policy for self deletion isn't also so trivial, initially I though, deletion of a answer you created shaw be simple erased from database at your conscious consent.

But good answers shaw not be simple erased based on ownership, the ownership of a good answer (which doesn't need to be an accepted answer) shaw be from stackoverflow, maybe answers with 0 votes could be trivially self-deleted... well, in this case I don't have though too much.

Answer (score 9):

> Isn't it a bit extreme to have a bunch of answers deleted without even knowing they were? Shouldn't they be at your profile, marked as deleted so you get the chance to improve them?

The vast majority of people posting links in answers have nefarious intentions - they shouldn't be assisted in learning how to get their content into the system after all. (Not you, but real spammers.)

And in general - there's a *lot* of help resources for people who want to find out how to write good answers; if further information is required, there's Meta where people will always find somebody to explain things for them. Anybody with half a brain can learn how to write good answers ("good" as defined by the standards of this site). That's the way it worked for your [recent incident](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122663/why-were-my-answers-about-using-a-library-ive-created-deleted), and if I'm not mistaken, despite all the downvoting etc., it worked okay and there was a real discussion.

I agree it's not a 100% nice user experience to have  contributions deleted without a chance to find them again, but in the overwhelming majority of cases, I dare say it doesn't matter much: making people aware that their stuff was deleted would cause much more trouble than a (maybe) improved answer would add value to the site. *Usually* (not in your specific case, but in most others) people who have their answers deleted don't have much to contribute to the site anyway, and it's impossible to try and educate every one of them.

> But good answers shaw not be simple erased based on ownership, the ownership of a good answer (which doesn't need to be an accepted answer) shaw be from stackoverflow, maybe answers with 0 votes could be trivially self-deleted... well, in this case I don't have though too much.

I totally agree. Once a user posts a contribution to the site, under the [CC-Wiki license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), Stack Overflow has an irrevocable right to publish it. Self-deletion is being allowed as a matter of courtesy - to some extent. People deleting all their answers in rage get stopped, and their deletions are rolled back. Also, self-deletions are impossible [if an answer has one or more upvotes.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented) Deleting 0-voted contributions can be done with one click AFAIK.

Comment: Hi Pekka, I can't concur cuz:

Deletion from profile:

  Nefarious user: cannot list his answers at profile, but real nefarious dudes maintain a list of them, and normal ones will not care for his given answers.

  Non-nefarious user: cannot list his answers at profile, and probably will not have a list of them, they are non-nefarious.

Without deletion from profile:

   Nefarious user: Given the previous perspective of a real nefarious user and a normal one, "without deletion from profile" doesn't really matter.

   Non-nefarious user: I got a bunch of questions deleted, what have I done?

Comment: I have asked for my answers at twitter, only the moderator had them... I just needed this questions flagged as deleted at my profile, for at last a period of time before vanishing, to go on my own to improve them and flag them for undeletion.

Comment: @Chico fair enough, you've got a point there.